# SharePoint library Document Title and Item title not synced

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a strange issue on a few of my webApplications.

When we upload a word document (with title property filled), it auto populates the document library item  title.

However, when we modify the document library item title and download the document, I still see the old document title and not the one that I modified.